# How can I enable my button on checked the checkbox

Tags: javascript

```
function addHeadCol(row, dindex) {
    var td = document.createElement('TD');
    td.setAttribute("class", "bs-checkbox print_hide");
    var chk = document.createElement("input");
    chk.setAttribute("data-index", dindex);
    chk.name = "btSelectItem";
    chk.type = "checkbox";
    td.appendChild(chk);
    row.appendChild(td);
}
```

This code creating checkboxes dynamically. I want to enable a button on checked the checkbox?

Comment: Where is the button here?

Comment: show your html code

Comment: <button id="delete" class="btn btn-default btn-sm print_hide" disabled="disabled">
           <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash">&nbsp;</span>Delete </button>

Answer (score 0):

Please find working solution below:

```js
function display() {
  alert('hello!');
}

function addHeadCol(row, dindex) {
  var td = document.createElement('TD');
  td.setAttribute("class", "bs-checkbox print_hide");
  var chk = document.createElement("input");
  chk.setAttribute("data-index", dindex);
  chk.name = "btSelectItem";
  chk.className = "chk"
  chk.type = "checkbox";
  chk.addEventListener("change", function(e) {
    checkboxes = document.getElementsByClassName('chk');
    var disableButton = true;
    for (var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
      if (checkboxes[i].checked) {
        disableButton = false;
      }
    }
    document.getElementById("btn").disabled = disableButton;
  });
  td.appendChild(chk);
  row.appendChild(td);
}

addHeadCol(document.getElementById('row1'), 1)
addHeadCol(document.getElementById('row2'), 2)
addHeadCol(document.getElementById('row3'), 3)
addHeadCol(document.getElementById('row4'), 4)
```

```html
<table>
  <tr id="row1"></tr>
  <tr id="row2"></tr>
  <tr id="row3"></tr>
  <tr id="row4"></tr>
</table>
<button id="btn" disabled onclick="display()">Click Me!</button>
```